# Merge Text Files From Folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I've been using the below code for awhile but have noticed that it is dropping off leading 0's.

I've tried changing the code to .OpenText and get error

> "Expected Function or variable".

Files that are loaded are .csv files converted to .txt before opened using a batch script.

```
Sub ExcelFileMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As    Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("H:\Reports\ahs\ProductDatabase\CV3 Tools\CV3 Product Merger\CV3 Files")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
'This is what I have tried changing to .OpenText and get returned error "Expected Function or variable"
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj) 


'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:AET" & Range("A2600").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial      Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
```

Here is the code I got after recording the macro. Now I'm trying to figure out how to mesh the 2.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;R:\ahs\ProductDatabase\CV3 Tools\CV3 Product Merger\CV3   Files\product_export1.txt" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "product_export1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194819.aspx , try `Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj,Format:=4)` to force `;` as separator or `Set bookList = Workbooks.OpenText(everyObj,Semicolon:=True)`

Comment: Still dropping leading 0's and changing sku's into dates, etc. If I can find a way for it to import the first column as text, that would be optimal i think.

Comment: You could activate your macro recorder, import CSV as data from Text, set encoding and all that jazz and *specify each columns data type*, finish, stop macro recorder. Use the recorded macro as basis.

Comment: I will look into recording a macro, although I'm not sure I will be able to make it work since I need variable number and name of files. Also a note is that although they were converted to txt, they are still comma delimited surrounded by double quotes. "10","11"

Comment: `variable number and name of files` - no problem there. _That_ can easily be handled. In this thread even. But this way you can custom set your column data types, delimiter and encoding, which you cannot when simply opening as csv.

Comment: Alright, I recorded the macro and made a poor attempt to implement. I couldn't use the VBA as it stands because the "With" command isn't acceptable where I place it. Posted code above for easy readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here's a mesh of your two, slightly adjusted:

```
Sub ExcelFileMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim con As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'change folder path of excel files here
Set dirObj = mergeObj.getfolder("H:\Reports\ahs\ProductDatabase\CV3 Tools\CV3 Product Merger\CV3 Files")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Add
    con = "TEXT;" & everyObj
    With bookList.Sheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        con, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "product_export1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
    'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
    'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
    'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
    Range("A2:AET" & Range("A2600").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
    Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    bookList.SaveAs "GiveItAPathAndFilenameHere"
    bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Would I change .Name = "product_export1" to .Name ="everyObj"? This is working, although I'm still having some formatting problems, but I can figure that out. So you created a varible called con, assigned it a text value and combined it with everyobj? Then did bookList.Sheets to call in the file? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, `con` holds the keyword TEXT; followed by the path to the file. For the .Name I would rather use `.Name= mergeObj.GetFileName(everyObj)`. This should give you the filename without path. `bookList.Sheets(1)` replaces the ÀctiveSheet` from the macro in order to keep it variable.